# Coredata insertion and Dispatch Groups

Tags: swift, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `createGroup()` function that uses a Dispatch Group to make sure all of the new group's data is uploaded to my remote database before continuing. I want to also save a copy of the data locally to the user's CoreData. However, I'm a bit new to this and unsure of where to safely execute the entity insertion.

The option I think would be best is to save it in the Dispatch Group's `notify` callback when everything is done uploading to the remote database.

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

func createGroup(onSccess completion:@escaping () -> Void) {
    let dataDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    dataDispatchGroup.enter()
    // Do asynchronous task 1
    dataDispatchGroup.enter()
    // Do asynchronous task 2

    dataDispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        // Do insertion here
        // NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName....
        completion()
    })
}
```

I've heard you need to be careful with saving to CoreData when dealing with threads. Is my approach safe or is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your actual CoreData code. Without further information, I would recommend to use `managedObjectContext.perform() { //do CD stuff, save context }`. The `dispatchGroup` part looks ok.

Comment: I was just going to do the normal `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName` there, I added it to my question.

Comment: That's fine. Your Core Data stuff happens on the current queue. Dont forget to `dataDispatchGroup.leave()`.